# How do you debug or step through the code in SQL Server Management Studio 18?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

SQL Server Management Studio used to have Debug functionality that would allow to step through the code and watch the values etc. Referring to [How to add the Debug button to SSMS v18?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221349/how-to-add-the-debug-button-to-ssms-v18), I understand that the functionality is removed from SQL Server Management Studio V18.1.

But what is the alternative now? How do you step through the code to pinpoint a bug in the code?

Answer (score 24):

You can use Visual Studio (the full IDE) to do it:

1. Use "Server Explorer" (Under the View menu) to connect to your DB
2. Right-click the DB and choose "New Query" (or find a stored procedure to debug)
3. Set a break point (F9 key or otherwise) on a line of SQL
4. Right-click inside the SQL editor and choose "Execute with Debugger"

Comment: 4 steps when it only took one is 17.9...This. Is. Progress!

Comment: @marc_s using the above method i manage to debug my queries which are using tables. However, queries which use view a get an error that the object does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem - I can SELECT * from views and step through sprocs that use views = Visual Studio 16.9.4.

Maybe find the view giving you a problem under Server Explorer, right click and "Show Results" to see if there is something wrong with it?

Comment: Noting that is not possible if you're coding in an environment where remote debugging is blocked by a firewall. Seems like the only other option is to downgrade.

Comment: i wonder how you might do this with a vm

Comment: that solutions worked for me thanks alot

Answer (score 8):

Your best option is to not upgrade version 18.X, but stay on 17.9 until the Microsoft Product Manager gets sacked.  A similar thing happened in going from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2k5.  Eventually, they capitulated and re-introduced the feature.

Comment: It's near the end of 2020, I am using 18.8. Still waiting for that manager of your.

Comment: We're still on 17.9.  Don't embolden the product team by installing 18.X.

Comment: It is quite possible to run 17.9 and 18.X on the same machine. I keep both, and use 17.9 for debugging.

Comment: It's July 2023,and still waiting for the feature to come back...

Answer (score 5):

Ta for answer above, but when trying to debug with Sever Explorer, I find that "SQL Debugging is not supported on Microsoft Azure SQL Database'... ho hum, so I downgrade to SSMS 17.9 or dump the database to local and do it there.

Nice, I just wanted to quickly debug something... by the time I've done that lot I'll have forgotten what the problem I was trying to fix was !

Answer (score 2):

It's deprecated, so you don't. Personally, I never use the feature and I'm assuming many others didn't either (which is why it's being retired).

The work around is to debug stored procedures by outputting values using `PRINT` or `RAISERROR`. Using `BEGIN TRAN` / `ROLLBACK` this works well because you can easily run code against the same data.

It's not the same as step through debugging, but it works.

Comment: That's terrible. It used to be a very convenient way to reproduce deadlocks by running queries step by step in two different tabs. Sad this was deprecated.

Comment: The question was, "How do I debug in SSMS."  Not, "What's your personal feelings about step-through debugging in SSMS."