# debugging in SSMS 18.2

Tags: sql, sql-server

New bie here for sql server. In latest SSMS 18.2 I don't see debugger, and I don't have a link to old SSMS 16. If I were to use latest SSMS 18.2 how do I debug stored procedures for sql server 2016?  whats the alternative?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you debug or step through the code in SQL Server Management Studio 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565764/how-do-you-debug-or-step-through-the-code-in-sql-server-management-studio-18)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a Debugger in the menus up to V17:

[image]

Unfortunately, Microsoft removed the Debugger in V18 and expect you to use Visual Studio to debug SQL Server.

You can still download SSMS V17.9 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#download-ssms-1791

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond, can you have two SSMS installed on one windows machine ?

Comment: Yes, I have both V17 and V18 installed on the same machine. However, don't discount the idea of using Visual Studio. The SQL editing window is much nicer than in SSMS.

Comment: BTW: @user8371676, the best thank you is to check off that this answer solved your question. Thanks.