# Debug in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms, ssms-18

In my SSMS I have not the Debug Menu

[image: debug]

And I don't know how to enable it but I can not add break points

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: [How to add the Debug button to SSMS v18?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221349/140734) TL;DR: It has been removed as it was deprecated. Use SSDT in Visual Studio if you need this functionality.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565764/how-do-you-debug-or-step-through-the-code-in-sql-server-management-studio-18

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be this utility is deprecated in v18