# SQL Server: how to start debugging, no debugger menu?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssms

Installed latest SQL Server Management Studio v18.4 on Windows 10.

There is no debugger menu.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/run-the-transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver15

How to start debugging a stored procedure?

Comment: have you tried Alt + F5 ?

Comment: Debugging functionality was removed from Sql Management Studio since version 18
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#180)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you debug or step through the code in SQL Server Management Studio 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565764/how-do-you-debug-or-step-through-the-code-in-sql-server-management-studio-18)

Answer (score -1):

I will put this as an concrete answer, Microsoft removed the debugging functionality of Management Studio since version 18 of the product.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#180)

Quote:

> Deprecated / Removed Features
>
> T-SQL Debugger

Comment: how do you do it in now?

Comment: @DanielA.White You probably found out already, but use SSDT instead.